# Is it possible to throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public void onClick(int row) {
    if (mItems.size() <= row) {
        return;
    }
    Action action = mItems.get(row);
}
```

Is it safe to call mItems.get()?

EDIT: From crash log, the `row` is -1, and then throw the exception.

EDIT: The safe writing is:

```
if (row < 0 || row >= mItems.size()) {
...
}
```

Comment: It looks safe enough. Are you getting an Exception? What problem are you trying to solve, all we can see is your attempted solution.

Comment: @Brian `size() == row` gets returned by the `if` condition check. So I guess it is safe.

Comment: @Keugyeol Yeah - same prob as my comment to the answer. My brain was refusing to read that comparison the correct direction because of how it was written.

Comment: @Elliott To avoid crash, I add `if` statement, but I still get this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is , will this code throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException then following case will

If a negative value is passed to row , this code with end up in an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: if row value is passed as -1 , the condition size ( say 0 ) <= -1 will not be met and the mItems.get(-1) will be called. Which will result in OOB

Comment: Gah, you're right ... in my head it was backwards because of how they wrote that. Apologies.

Comment: @ranjit I don't think `mItems.size()` will ever be a negative value so the `if` condition will always filter out the case of `row` being negative. Therefore, above code seems safe and won't throw an OOB exception.

Comment: @ranjit You are true, if row value is negative, it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException is an unchecked exception.  Therefore, the java compiler will not check if a given block of code throws it.

If this exception is being thrown, then you are  indexing out of the bounds of the array - as the name of the exception tells you.

Link discussing checked and unchecked exceptions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

EDIT:
In your particular instance, is another thread accessing mItems?  Because that could make the size of mItems change between the moment you check its size and the moment you index into it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks safe.

Your question doesn't seem to show your effort or research on the given problem.
Have you tried to compile and test run the code with certain values of `row`?

You could have figured it out by yourself while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

you can throw any type of exception no matter it is checked or unchecked.

only thing is for checked compiler forces you to handle but for unchecked like ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception compiler wont complaint.

in your code you can throw it like below

```
public void onClick(int row) {
    if (mItems.size() <= row) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    Action action = mItems.get(row);
}
```